# list_display - boolean icons not working for BooleanField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Simple situation, model:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

And ModelAdmin:

```
class ManufacturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_filter = ['assortment_type', 'active']
    ordering = ('priority',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',),}
    list_display = ('name', 'active')
```

Still in Admin active column is displayed as True/False and not as icon. I can create method and set Boolean = True attribute but I lost sorting ability for column. It's obvious that I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom method, then set `admin_order_field` to the field name and `boolean` as True

```
def my_function(self):
    # your stuff goes here
my_function.boolean = True
my_function.admin_order_field = 'active'
```

That should make it sortable ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/))

Comment: Thank you for your quick note, this is nice work-around but I just wonder why this is not working out of the box just with BooleanField.